# how to specifically add data to each item in array in php

Tags: php, sendgrid, sendgrid-api-v3

basically, I need to output a list of emails in a very specific way for the SendGrid API to understand. it looks like this.

```
{email:recipient1@example.com},
{email:recipient2@example.com},
{email:recipient3@example.com}
```

in essence, I need to just add the curly brackets and email: ,

I have no idea how to do this.

my code is this.

```
$e= array("recipient1@example.com", "recipient2@example.com", "recipient3@example.com");
foreach ($e as $x) {
   echo"{email:$x}, <br>";
}
```

I'm using echo because when I try to convert it into a var it either gives me an error code or just displays the last email in the $e array.

why is it SO DAMN hard to just add some stuff to each item in an array?

Comment: do you want output in JSON format? if yes what you are expecting is not valid JSON.

Comment: For future reference, if you are defining a variable inside a foreach loop you need to either make the variable an array where each loop just adds a new value to the array you're creating (like $e[] = "..."), or concatenate another way.  If you just define the variable each time (like $e = "..."), it does exactly that, and changes the value of $e until the loop stops.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works on my end...

```
$e= array("recipient1@example.com", "recipient2@example.com", "recipient3@example.com");
foreach ($e as $x) {
    $y[] = "{email:$x}";
}
$list = implode(",<br>", $y);
//print_r($list);
```

Comment: oh my god thank you! thank you. I'd kiss you If I could. I've been banging my head against the wall on this for so long.

Answer (score 0):

Valid JSON :

```
$e= array("recipient1@example.com", "recipient2@example.com", "recipient3@example.com");
$final_arr = [];
foreach ($e as $x) {
   $final_arr[]['email'] = $x;
}
/* 
echo json_encode($final_arr); results :-

[{"email":"recipient1@example.com"},
{"email":"recipient2@example.com"},
{"email":"recipient3@example.com"}]

*/
```